# How to retrieve values from nested json variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json

I am new to mySQL and I need help extracting values from a Json variable.
Please see the example bellow.

```
@Model ='{
    "SortOptions": [{
            "SortBy": "[FirstName]",
            "SortDir": "DESC"
        },
        {
            "SortBy": "[LastName]",
            "SortDir": "DESC"
        }
    ]
}';
```

I need to extract SortBy and SortDir Key values and create an expression .Expected result

```
@SortOptions = '[FirstName] DESC [LastName] DESC'
```

Comment: What programming language are you using.. Trust me you don't want to parse dynamic JSON with MySQL.

Comment: Node js. I am using this to build dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

You can extract information from a JSON using JSON_EXTRACT.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths